# Can someone walk me through howto get started with libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I just got started with Libgdx and I find really hard to organize the code.
Could someone please tell me what should i start to write first and with  what to move on after that. I have read tutorials online but i find them confusing

Comment: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html

Comment: I would say the tutorial [A Simple Game](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game)  is the best starting point you can have.
Just follow from top to bottom, and you'll get a great overview on how libGDX works.
After that go to the second tutorial [Extending the simple game](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending%20the%20Simple%20Game), and you'll be ready to fly by your own means.

Answer (score 1):

Here some tutorials for a quick start :

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game

http://www.toxsickproductions.com/libgdx/

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Video-Tutorial-Series.aspx

A YouTube playlist about creating a simple game in Java using Eclipse, LibGDX and Box2D :
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXY8okVWvwZ0JOwHiH1TntAdq-UDPnC2L

A very useful Libgdx cookbook :
https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/libgdx-cross-platform-game-development-cookbook

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That drop/bucket game example is great way to start. But check out also this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_hp6vMeewQ

Answer (score 0):

I started a project that wants help people getting start with libGDX. A sort of playground where you can put your experiments. Hosted on github : https://github.com/edesdan/libgdx-playground . It could be useful to you while reading the suggested tutorials. ﻿